# Simple three div layout question

Tags: html, css, layout

I am struggling for few days with DIV HTML layout I was hoping to get some help,

Current point in the document is three DIV'S, the three divs are contained in "container" div (180*400 px)

Top two DIV'S in the container split 50% of the width (right is logo, left is date)

And additional div (green color) take the rest of the height (400px - 100px of logo)

I am unable to set the (White) DIV to occupy all the remaining 50% width 
also i am unable to tell the bottom div (Green) to occupy 100% of the remaining height

Here is an illustration:

http://jsfiddle.net/dwuZp/6/

Thank you for your help (and patience)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is what you want.  It is hard to tell from the question.  Here is what I did though:

1. Added explicit `width`s to your top `floated` elements.  Floats need widths in order to float properly.
2. Added explicit `height`s to your `time` and `logo` divs.

Hopefully that comes close.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/dwuZp/9/

Comment: One last thing, I found out that if "icons" div is 100% height of its container then it is acceding the container div by an inch (exceeds as the height of "logo" div), 

How do I set the inner "icons" div to be 100% width of the rest of its parent "logoTimeAndIcons" div?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here, @user648026.  Can you give me more info?

Comment: Thank you Jason, I posted new question for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The green div IS occupying 100% of the remaining container height, it's just that ***its*** container div, `#logoTimeAndIcons`, isn't the full height of ***its*** container div, `#container`.

Also, the logo image is 100px, which is 10px more than 50% of the 180px width of the container...